# Why does .NET Core 2.0 perform worse than .NET Framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've wrote a program that creates 4 threads which each sort 20.000 numbers from low to high 50 times. I've runned this test several times on .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.1. In this test .NET Framework always outperforms .NET Core.

**Setup**

- .NET Core in release mode & published
- Windows 10, i7 duo core, 4 threads (hyperthreading)

The following code has been used to benchmark the two frameworks.

```
static void Main()
    {
        const int amountParallel = 4;
        var globalStopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        globalStopwatch.Start();

        var tasks = new Task<double[]>[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < amountParallel; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Start();
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        globalStopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Averages: {0}ms", tasks.SelectMany(r => r.Result).Average(x => x));
        Console.WriteLine("Time completed: {0}", globalStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    private static Task<double[]> Start()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var numbersToSort = new int[20000];

            var globalStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            var individualStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            var stopwatchTimes = new double[50];
            int temp;

            globalStopwatch.Start();

            for (int i = 0; 50 > i; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Running task: {0}", i);
                numbersToSort = Enumerable.Range(0, 20000).Reverse().ToArray();
                individualStopwatch.Start();

                for (int indexNumberArray = 0; numbersToSort.Length > indexNumberArray; indexNumberArray++)
                {
                    for (int sort = 0; numbersToSort.Length - 1 > sort; sort++)
                    {
                        if (numbersToSort[sort] > numbersToSort[sort + 1])
                        {
                            temp = numbersToSort[sort + 1];
                            numbersToSort[sort + 1] = numbersToSort[sort];
                            numbersToSort[sort] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }

                individualStopwatch.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine("Task {0} completed, took: {1}ms", i, Math.Round(individualStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));

                stopwatchTimes[i] = individualStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

                individualStopwatch.Reset();
            }

            globalStopwatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Total time: {0}s", Math.Round(globalStopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, 2));
            Console.WriteLine("Average: {0}ms", Math.Round(stopwatchTimes.Average(time => time)));

            return stopwatchTimes;
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
```

Test results:

**.NET Core**

- Average: 761ms
- Total time: 38s

**.NET Framework**

- Average: 638ms
- Total time: 32s

.NET Core isn't slower on only CPU related tasks. It's also slower on disk I/O tasks.

Any idea's why .NET Core is a bit slower on this part? Are there changes I can make to improve the performance of .NET Core?

Comment: @series0ne I guess so. According to https://andrewlock.net/understanding-net-core-netstandard-and-asp-net-core/ .NET Core seems to have an extra layer called the Runtime Adaptation Layer. This probably causes the overhead.

Comment: Try https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet to get more accurate results. Make sure to run the tests in Release configuration.

Comment: Comparing apples and oranges is an easy mistake.  A .NETFramework project by default runs 32-bit code, .NETCore likes 64-bit code.  Very different fruits on floating point-heavy code.  Untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant You are completely right! I've re-runned the tests are and both frameworks perform pretty much the same. If you create an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Score another one for psychic debugging.  Feel free to use the guess to complete this Q+A.

Comment: Another point of note is that the desktop x86 JIT is a separate code base from the x64 JIT. For 64-bit, both .NET Framework and .NET Core use RyuJIT now; for 32-bit .NET Core still uses RyuJIT, but .NET Framework uses the legacy JIT, so you've got both different bitness and a different jitter.

Comment: @Jamie you can post answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: can you share your machine hardware info ,  as i am using macbook pro 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7 and result like this 
Total time: 161.82s
Average: 3235ms
Task 49 completed, took: 2934ms
Task 49 completed, took: 2928ms
Total time: 162.03s
Total time: 162.03s
Task 49 completed, took: 2943ms
Total time: 162.03s
Average: 3239ms
Average: 3236ms
Average: 3239ms
Averages: 3237.3444ms
Time completed: 162097.426

Comment: I have similar experience with protobuf-net serializeration. Preparing large set of data a serializing/deserializing is faster in net framework on windows and also on Linux arm with mono. Tested with net core 3.1 and mono 6.6

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.NET Framework projects default to 32-bit code. This option is visible in the build settings of a project and selected by default. .NET Core projects default to 64-bit code. If you untick the "Prefer 32-bit" box you will notice .NET Framework drops in performance.

> Another point of note is that the desktop x86 JIT is a separate code
>   base from the x64 JIT. For 64-bit, both .NET Framework and .NET Core
>   use RyuJIT now; for 32-bit .NET Core still uses RyuJIT, but .NET
>   Framework uses the legacy JIT, so you've got both different bitness
>   and a different jitter.

The answers were provided in the comments by Hans Passant and Jeroen Mostert.

Answer (score 10):

This should be fixed in .Net Core 2.0.7 and .Net Framework 4.7.2, via https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/15323

Root cause was a bug in the JIT's Common Subexpression Elimination (aka CSE) optimization. See issue (linked from PR) for gory details.